# How to create a custom Quartz trigger?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I searched google but couldn't find articles/tutorials on how to create a custom trigger. Any pointers/suggestions are helpful. The custom trigger should wait until the below two conditions are met and then trigger a job

1. Time is past 5 PM
2. A record with particular value (say a column value for row id 10 is changed to "START") has arrived in a given table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Quartz before, but looking at the javadoc `Trigger` looks hard enough to implement. Can't you just run your job every minute or hour or whatever and put something like the following up the top:

```
if (!new org.joda.time.DateTime().getHourOfDay() >= 17 || !databaseRowIsInPlace()) {
    return;
}

// Do complicated work
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [sjr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373653/sjr). I would just create a `CronTrigger` with cronExpression `0 0/5 17-23 * * ?` (so it would fire every 5 minutes starting at 5 PM - adjust the frequency depending on your exact requirements) , and then check the database conditions upon job execution.